# What is wrong with my apache2 server?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost, syntax

I edited the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default and then tried to restart my apache server and this error came up:

```
Syntax error on line 20 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.save:
unknown order
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Here is what the 000-default file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is that file the `000-default.save` file, or a `000-default` file?  There might be a sneaky character on that `Order` line it's referring to, can you try deleting and re-typing the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Just a quick note to say, one way to avoid having your Apache server hosed if the config file chokes due to a change is to first `reload` Apache to see how it parses the config.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

The nice thing about `reload` is it will attempt to reload the settings in a config file, but it won’t force the server to stop or restart. If it chokes, it will send up an alert, but your Apache server is still running smoothly.  If after a `reload` all is clean, you can then `restart` Apache to force settings if you wish.

Now, specific to your question the error states:

> Syntax error on line 20 of
>   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**000-default.save**:  unknown order  Action
>   'configtest' failed.

But then you are referring to:

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**000-default**

Seems like something went amiss when you were editing the `000-default` file since that `.save` file shows up when a crash or some other non-normal way of exiting the editor happens.

Also, there should be only one `000-default` and not a `000-default.save`.

I would look in this file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default
```

Does that look right? No, then look here:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.save
```

Does that look right? Then replace the contents of `000-default` with `000-default.save`?

Once you have `sites-available` ironed out, go over to this directory:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

And clean it up. Remove any files named `000-default` or `000-default.save` and create a proper symbolic link from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Note that when in `sites-available` the file is named `default` but when it is linked into `sites-enabled` it gets named `000-default` to set the load order.